# how to set min-height of row of blocktable in rml

Tags: height, row, rml

How to set min-height of row of `blocktable` in `rml`? I read the `rml-reference` and can't find any related content. I only found the attr: `rowHeights`, But it seems that it just set a fixed height, the content will flow out. I wanna set a base height,and when the content increases the height of row increases too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: better start using qweb instead. RML is pretty much dead anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible for v7 or lower (v8/trunk no idea).

As you've stated right, rowHeights sets fixed heights for rows and without that attribute you will have auto-sized heights.